# How do I convert a tensor object to an array without adding to graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I basically have a for loop where I need to run a prediction in order to calculate something.

```py
for i in range(0,6,1):
        episodes, n_actions = util.record_episode(env,num = 2)
        data, actions, targets = util.forward_data(episodes)
        new_image, pred_image, action = latent_model.predict([(data - np.mean(data, axis=0)) / 255])
        latent_actions = tf.Variable(models.argmin_mse(new_image,np.moveaxis(np.repeat(np.array([targets]),4,axis = 0),0,1)))
```

However, when I go for a large number of episodes I end up running out of memory. I tried to make the computational graph static to see whether or not something funny was happening. It turns out that 'tf.Variable' is adding something to the graph?

Could someone help me convert my tensor to numpy array without running out of memory?